# Upload picture works on local but not after deployment with nginx

Tags: javascript, meteor, nginx

I have a meteor application and I have a profile picture that I want to change by uploading a new one. So, I upload an image in a folder and I save the url in a mongo database. This is work very well in local but when I deploy the application with nginx, this doesn't work anymore.

This is my javascript code on client side :

```
Template.profile.events({
    'change #imgUploadButton' : function(event){
        var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var imgtag = document.getElementById("imageTool");
        imgtag.title = selectedFile.name;
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            imgtag.src = event.target.result;
            Meteor.call('saveProfilePicture', selectedFile.name, reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
    }
});
```

So, I call a meteor method :

```
Meteor.methods({
  saveProfilePicture: function(fileName, fileData) {
    var fs = Npm.require('fs');
    var path = process.env.PWD + '/var/profilePictures/';

   base64Data  =   fileData.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
   base64Data  +=  base64Data.replace('+', ' ');
   binaryData  =   new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64').toString('binary');
   var pictureName = currentUserId + '_' + fileName;
   pictureName = pictureName.replace(/\s/g, '');

   fs.writeFile(path + pictureName, binaryData, "binary", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (err) {
    if (err) {
            throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err));
          } else {
            insertionProfilePicture(fileName);
          }
     }));
   }
});
```

And :

```
var insertionProfilePicture = function(fileName){
   var name = currentUserId + '_' + fileName;
   name = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
   Meteor.users.update({_id: currentUserId},{$set:{profilePicture: 
   "var/profilePictures/" + name}}); 
}
```

So, do you know why it works on local but not after the deployment with nginx ?

EDIT :
It's maybe a problem of permissions with nginx.
In the file `/etc/nginx/site-enabled/myApp`, I have :

```
# pass all requests to Meteor
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # allow websockets
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; # preserve client IP

    # this setting allows the browser to cache the application in a way compatible with Meteor
    # on every applicaiton update the name of CSS and JS file is different, so they can be cache infinitely (here: 30 days)
    # the root path (/) MUST NOT be cached
    if ($uri != '/') {
        expires 30d;
    }
}
location /static/ {
    root /var/uploads;
}
```

So, maybe I need to make something with the location config but I try :

```
location /profilePictures/ {
    root/var/profilePictures;
}
```

and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include the error log? I suspect it's just that meteor doesn't have write permissions to the folder you're trying to use.

Comment: In the file `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, I have `2017/06/25 14:00:06 [error] 26258#0: *28598 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.69.36.127, server: "myAdress", request: "POST /sockjs/890/f5ote8kw/xhr HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sockjs/890/f5ote8kw/xhr", host: "myAdress", referrer: "myAdress/login"`

Comment: Looks like a connectivity / firewall issue